# How EOF works in C?

Tags: c, eof

Below is a sample code

```
while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) 
{ 
      putchar(c);  
}
```

I can understand most of the part but not that EOF (End of file).

Comment: Duplicate question. Search SO for this

Answer (score 1):

It's easy. The `EOF` is a constant equal to `-1` which is returned by `getchar()` when the standard input has reached the and and cannot give you many more characters.